# Providing R/W access to phpmyadmin page

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

How do i provide read and write access to my teammate for the php myadmin page(local host/MySQL) of the server?I am using wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a MySQL user with `Read` and `Write` Privileges.

Login as root user and create new user with required privileges

```
GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

**Explanation**

`GRANT` - This is the command used to create users and grant rights to databases, tables, etc.

`SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE`  - This tells it the user will have these privileges.

`db_name.*` - This instructions MySQL to apply these rights for the use onto the full dbtest database. You can replace the * with specific table names or store routines if you wish.

`TO 'user'@'hostname'` - 'user' is the of the user account you are creating. Note: You must have the single quotes in there. 'hostname' tells MySQL what hosts the user can connect from. If you only want it from the same machine, use localhost

`IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` - As you would have guessed, this sets the password for that user.

Have a look at [**Adding User Accounts in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: what do i write in 'host' and 'password' ? the ip address and windows password?

Comment: For `phpmyadmin` host will be `localhost` and you can set password as you want which user will use to login mysql. it is not the windows password

Comment: How should the other user access this phpmyadmin page?

Comment: using this as URL `yourmachineip/phpmyadmin`

Comment: It says you dont have permission to view localhost/mysql on this server.